# Mongoose: Consume error in post hook

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an `Express.js` app backed with `MongoDB` using `Mongoose`. I need to ignore a duplicate key error from MongoDB (error code 11000) and still return a 204 HTTP response.  The idea is to use the `post` hook on `save`, consume the error and ignore it.

**Service layer**

```
const createMyModel = (req, res, next) => {
  MyModel.create({...data})
  .then(createRes => res.status(204).send())
  .catch(next)
}
```

**Schema - save hook**

```
MySchema.post('save', (err, res, next) => {
  if (!err || (err.name === 'MongoError' && err.code === 11000)) {
    // The duplicate key error is caught here but somehow
    // the catch on my service layer gets triggered 
    next();
  }else{
    next(err)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `next` callback in `Mongoose` keeps track of something called a `firstError`. This is where internal errors like Duplicate Key Error get stored. This prevents the user from overriding the error state and calling next would always result in checking for `firstError` and triggering a promise rejection even if one tries to call `next()` or `next(null)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore them completely I think you could set emitIndexErrors to false in the schema.options object.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#emitIndexErrors

Comment: Good to know about emitIndexErrors but that doesn't quite solve my problem. The ask is to consume just one particular error in a post hook.